# C++ and friendship of nested private classes

Tags: c++, friend, nested-class

I have 2 classes like the dummy one below

```
   class CA
   {
   private:
    class Impl;
   };

   class Cb
   {
   private:
    friend class CA::Impl;
   }
```

This code is giving me compilation error saying that class CA::Impl is private. Is it really not possible to put in place friendship for nested private classes? What else can I do to implement this semantic?

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? Do you expect to be able to access any other `private` member of `CA`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You, Adam, and Steve**

Imagine that there is this celebrity named *Adam Stackie*, who has a friend named *Steve*.

Wouldn't it be weird if you by knowing certain things about *Adam*, even though you are not his friend, just assumed that you and *Steve* were close enough for you to grab him in public?

A class is not implicitly a friend of a friend, nor is it implicitly a friend of something which it can reach into certain parts off.

---

**A little bit more serious**

To make your snippet work you will either have to

- Make `Cb` a friend of `CA`, by putting in a forward- and a friend-declaration for `Cb` in `CA`
  , or;
- make `CA::Impl` public, or;
- in any other way make sure that `Cb` can grab onto `CA::Impl`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but you need to make `Cb` a friend of `CA` so it will be allowed to access its private members. For example:

```
class Cb;

class CA
{
   friend class Cb;

private:
   class Impl;
};

class Cb
{
private:
   friend class CA::Impl;
};
```